# Runtime issues in GCC 4.4.5 on RedHat, but works fine on Apple llvm 4.2?

Tags: c++, gcc, llvm

So I have a project that I have been compiling on the apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 compiler. The project will compile with GCC 4.4.5 on RedHat linux but there are some very strange things going on in the runtime. There are no runtime errors, but the program output is completely different.

I am pretty terrible with GDB so I am and I need to submit this project by midnight tonight for school. Could anyone possibly suggest some things that come to mind that might be causing this? Maybe some known differences between these two compilers that could give me somewhere to look?

I realize this is very vague, I am trying to learn to use gdb so I can figure out what is happening.

Comment: Are you getting compiler warnings?

Comment: If the program output is not the same then it is very likely that you are misusing the language and are causing undefined behavior. It is very unlikely that it is a difference in the compilers. Have you initialized all variables before use? Are you allocating and using memory correctly within bounds. Are variables in function initialized to default values?

Comment: Are both builds 64-bit? Have you tried the static analyzer?

Comment: Better than going at it with `gdb` is to turn on all compiler warnings: `-Wall -Wextra`. Try this with both the LLVM and the `gcc(1)` compiler -- one might catch something the other misses. Incidentally, I strongly doubt the _compiler_ is the problem -- I fully expect it to be slight differences in _libraries_ before I'd suspect the compilers themselves.

Comment: @Pubby The only compiler warning I get is about an unused variable, that is with `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: @FirozeLafeer both systems are 64 bits, and I don't know what the static analyzer is but I will look into it

Comment: @AdrianCornish That was exactly the list of questions that I needed. I had forgotten to initialize a variable to zero, which apparently the llvm does automatically. If you want to post it as an answer, It might be helpful as a list of checks in case some burnt out college student finds themselves in the same predicament later. If not then I will. Thanks so much.

Comment: I've debugged the same issue many years ago - VMS C compilers used to initialize local variable to zero too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I went through the checklist suggested by @AdrianCornish :

"If the program output is not the same then it is very likely that you are misusing the        language and are causing undefined behavior. It is very unlikely that it is a difference in the compilers. Have you initialized all variables before use? Are you allocating and using memory correctly within bounds. Are variables in function initialized to default values?" – Adrian Cornish

Through this I discovered that there was an integer variable which I had forgotten to initialize to zero in my constructor. Apparently the llvm will automatically initialize variables to zero, while gcc does not.

Answer (score 1):

As found by @weezbizzle - the compilers behave differently and one default initializes member variables.